# fprintf on (unterminated?) C-string doesn't spew garbage or segfault -- undefined behavior?

Tags: c, c-strings, mmap, null-terminated

I recently learned (initially from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770672/parse-json-file-using-json-c)) how to use `mmap` to quickly read a file in *C*, as in this example code:

```
// main.c
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define INPUT_FILE "test.txt"

int main(int argc, char* argv) {
  struct stat ss;

  if (stat(INPUT_FILE, &ss)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "stat err: %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }

  {
    int fd = open(INPUT_FILE, O_RDONLY);
    char* mapped = mmap(NULL, ss.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);

    close(fd);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", mapped);
    munmap(mapped, ss.st_size);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My understanding is that this use of `mmap` returns a pointer to *length* heap-allocated bytes.
I've tested this on plain text files, that are not explicitly null-terminated, e.g. a file with the 13-byte ascii string "hello, world!":

```
$ cat ./test.txt
hello, world!$
$ stat ./test.txt
  File: ./test.txt
  Size: 13              Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 810h/2064d      Inode: 52441       Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   user)   Gid: ( 1000/   user)
Access: 2022-10-25 20:30:52.563772200 -0700
Modify: 2022-10-25 20:30:45.623772200 -0700
Change: 2022-10-25 20:30:45.623772200 -0700
 Birth: -
```

When I run my compiled code, it never segfaults or spews garbage -- the classic symptoms of printing an unterminated C-string.

When I run my executable through *gdb*, `mapped[13]` is always `'\0'`.

**Is this undefined behavior?**

I can't see how it's possible that the bytes that are memory-mapped from the input file are reliably NULL-terminated.
For a 13-byte string, the "equivalent" that I would have normally done with `malloc` and `read` would be to allocate a 14-byte array, read from file to memory, then *explicitly set byte 13 (0-based) to `'\0'`.*

Comment: Typical OS behavior is to clear memory before providing it to a new process (for security reasons). And "clear" usually means "set all bytes to 0", but it could just as easily be "set all bytes to 0xAA". So yes, undefined behavior as far as the C standard is concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mmap` returns a pointer to whole pages allocated by the kernel. It doesn't go through `malloc`. Pages are usually 4096 bytes each and apparently the kernel fills the extra bytes with zeroes, not with garbage.

Comment: Although slightly off-topic here, the page size is `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` from `unistd.h`.